# ¿Qué significa el operador : después de un for o un if?

Tags: php

¿Que significa `:` (que va después del if y del for) en el siguiente código?

```
<?php if(isset($_layoutParams['menu'])): ?>
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($_layoutParams['menu']); $i++): ?>

          <li><a href="<?php echo $_layoutParams['menu'][$i]['enlace']; ?>"> <?php echo $_layoutParams['menu'][$i]['titulo']; ?> </a></li>

        <?php endfor; ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

¿Por qué no funciona si ellos(:)? Normalmente un for no necesita de este operador (si alguien sabe como se llama se lo agradezco) por lo que me resulta extraño. El mas parecido que conozco es el ternario pero no tiene nada que ver con este ¿verdad?

Comment: Es otra forma de escribir el codigo. Podrias sustituir ese `:` por `{`, y el `endfor` por la llave cerrada ´}´

Comment: La respuesta viene en el manual de PHP te dejo el siguiente link para que le des una revisada [sintaxis](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), para mi es una buena manera de combinar el PHP con el HTML teniendo un orden y no estar abriendo y cerrando etiquetas `<?php  ?>`

Answer (score 7):

Es una [sintaxis alternativa](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php). Las siguientes piezas de código son exactamente lo mismo:

```
<?php if(isset($_layoutParams['menu'])): ?>
  <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($_layoutParams['menu']); $i++): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_layoutParams['menu'][$i]['enlace']; ?>"> <?php echo $_layoutParams['menu'][$i]['titulo']; ?> </a></li>
  <?php endfor; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```
<?php if(isset($_layoutParams['menu'])) { ?>
  <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($_layoutParams['menu']); $i++) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $_layoutParams['menu'][$i]['enlace']; ?>"> <?php echo $_layoutParams['menu'][$i]['titulo']; ?> </a></li>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Son muy útiles para cuando tienes múltiples condiciones abiertas a la vez. Compara lo siguiente:

```
      <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

```
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

La segunda opción deja mucho más claro cuáles son las estructuras de control que estás cerrando.